# Десантный и аэромобильный - синонимы?

Tags: синонимы

Есть ли разница между обозначениями рода войск: *десантные* и *аэромобильные*, или это синонимы?

Answer (score 3):

Нет, это не синонимы.

Десантные войска - это те, которые десантируются с самолётов или кораблей, а аэромобильные - те, что передвигаются с помощью воздушного транспорта (как правило, вертолётов). Т. е. десантные войска вступают в бой непосредственно после высадки, а аэромобильная бригада с помощью аэротранспорта передвигается, но высадка необязательно должна быть в боевой обстановке. Если мне не изменяет память, впервые аэромобильные подразделения стали использовать американцы во время войны во Вьетнаме.

Comment: Кстати, да. Но это уже тонкости тактического плана, чисто военные. Современные технологии ведения войны. Сегодня так, завтра этак... Можно десант и с вертолетов выбрасывать, что сейчас и делают. Если же ставить вопрос ребром о синонимичности значений, то такие тонкости и не нужны. Ясно, что синонимичности здесь нету.

Answer (score 0):

Это *не* синонимы с точки зрения русского языка. А вот с точки зрения минобороны - это надо у них спрашивать. В принципе - да, в современных войсках десантные - это и есть аэромобильные. Но это вопрос Устава (в широком смысле), а устав комментировать должны те, кто его пишет. Так что лучше не злоупотреблять тут своим пониманием.

Comment: Вы сами себе противоречите. Впрочем, не удивительно.

Comment: И десант и аэромобиль - специальные войска предназначенные для высадки или высаженные на территорию противника для ведения там боевых действий.

Comment: Серж, я себе не противоречу. И хватит уже об этом, если Вы не в состоянии объяснить, что Вам не нравится в моем тексте, то молчите уж. Слово "Десант" появилось задолго до того, как нечто стало летать по воздуху. Десанты изначально были морскими. И в Отечественную так и понималось.

Comment: Я прекрасно знаю, когда появился десант. Если слова появились в разное время, это еще не значит, что не могут быть синонимами. В Отечественную так и понималось много чего могло пониматься. Нас интересует современное значение, а не старое. Сегодня десанты могут перемещаться и по воздуху.

Comment: *И десант и аэромобиль* - ну и что?  А сырник и творожник - синонимы. А саыр и творог - нет. И вообще, формулируйте свою мысль так, чтобы можно было понять, зачем она тут. Надоело догадываться, что у Вас там замкнуло на ассоциативном уровне.  *Десант - это высадка. аэромобиль - машина, техника. Ни то, ни другое **войсками** не является, хотя и имеет к ним отношение**.

Comment: Вы и сами говорите: "в современных войсках десантные - это и есть аэромобильные".

Comment: *Вы и сами говорите: "в современных войсках десантные - это и есть аэромобильные"* - И что?

Comment: И то и другое имеют отношение к высадки. десантное войско высаживается с помощью парашюта, аэромобильное - средствами воздушной доставки (вертолетами) посадочным способом.

Comment: И что? А Волга впадает в Каспийское море. Я же на этом основании не утверждаю, что Волга и Каспий - синонимы?

Comment: Серж, давайте кончать уже. Сдается мне, что Вы уже сами забыли, что хотели возразить. Сказал уже, хотите общаться - извольте объясняться законченными мыслями.

Answer (score -1):

По данным Википедии, это синонимы.

В разных странах **воздушно-десантные войска называют по-разному:** воздушная пехота[2], крылатая пехота, силы (войска) быстрого реагирования, **аэромобильные войска**, высокомобильные десантные войска, коммандос (британские коммандос) и другие.

Comment: В вопросе войска десантные, а не воздушно-десантные. Вы опять поспешили.